# how i can set two listview in one page in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have two listview on one page, but the problem is when refreshing the list view only one list be refreshed and when scrolling the listview also one listview scrolling,

for more information, I can't merge two listviews in one because I have some cases do with attachment listview

**the xaml code**

```
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="detailsList" HeightRequest="5000" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}" 
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                          HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <ListView x:Name="Attachments" ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true" SelectionMode="None"
                                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Tapped="Attachment_Tapped">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Value.AttachmentTitle}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                    <Image Source="attach.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Image>
                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
```

I try to do this code but still not working, and I try to do `ListView.FooterTemplate` But to no avail

```
          <StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="detailsList" HeightRequest="5000" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}" 
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListView x:Name="Attachments" ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}" 
                                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell Tapped="Attachment_Tapped">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Value.AttachmentTitle}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                    <Image Source="attach.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Image>
                                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                                    <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <es:Label Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                        <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                              HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

thank you advance :)

Comment: Why do you have two different lists on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I have  replaced  `<ListView.HeaderTemplate>` to `</ListView.Footer>`

this XAML code works fine

```
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <ListView x:Name="Attachments" ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true" SelectionMode="None"
                                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell Tapped="Attachment_Tapped">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <!--<es:Label Text="{Binding Value.AttachmentTitle}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>-->
                                                <Image Source="attach.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Image>
                                                <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                                <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="#795C8E" 
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </ListView.Footer>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <es:Label Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="#eeeeee" HeightRequest="2" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,2">
                                        <es:Label Text="{Binding Key}" WidthRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="100" TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                              HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```